# Passing "gets" c language function input parameter from an inline python code

Tags: python, bash, gets

How can I pass output of a Python script to gets function of a c program ? My c program code is below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
   char name[64];
   printf("%p\n", name);
   fflush(stdout);
   puts("What's your name?");
   fflush(stdout);
   gets(name);
   printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
   return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is something like below:

```
$./a.out "$(python -c 'print "A"*1000')"
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: First you should have looked at how to pass arguments to main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send data from the stdout of one command into the stdin of another command, you need a "pipe":

```
python -c 'print "A"*1000' | ./a.out
```

I assume that the buffer overrun here is deliberate, so I'll leave out the lecture about the unsafety of `gets`.

Normally, a command-line utility will acquire its input from the argument array (`argv` in the parameters to `main`), which usually avoids the need for copying the data and thus any risk if a buffer overrun.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I intentionally put that buffer overrun on the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 python -c 'print "A"*1000'
```

will print `A` thousand times. If you wish to pass this to the C programme then you need a buffer of size at-least one greater than `1000`, the extra 1 is to accommodate the null character.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> // for strcpy
int main(int agrc, char* argv[])  
// int argc- is for number of arguments
// char* argv[] - argument strings separated by spaced
// each argument can be accessed by argv[1],argv[2] & so on
{
   char name[1001]=""; 
   // initialize name to null & 1001 for the reason mentioned above
   printf("%s\n", name); 
   // %p specifier is for the pointer,i used %s here for the string
   fflush(stdout);
   /* 
    * This part of your code is useless if you wish
    * to store the name from the argument.
   puts("What's your name?");
   fflush(stdout);
   gets(name);
   */
   strcpy(name,argv[1]); // copying the cmd line argument to name.
   printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
   return 0;
}
```

Now run it like

```
$./a.out "$(python -c 'print "A"*1000')"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the user is looking for. If so , what is the purpose of ` gets(name);` in the original code(which you commented)?

Comment: @mona_sax : I can't confirm it either without some additional information from the op in this regard

Comment: What is the point of copying the argument, in your formulation?